# sorting a list of strings by their length not working

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I was wondering why my lists of strings are not sorting properly. I type in a 4 word sentence then it is permuted 24 times and then I want it to sort those sentences. Except when I use

```
def my4sort(alist): #sorts the list of strings
  return(sorted(alist, key=len))
```

> Permutation 0: ' bob is programming lots ' when sorted gives ' bob is programming lots '
>
> Permutation 1: ' bob is lots programming ' when sorted gives ' bob is lots programming '
>
> Permutation 2: ' bob programming is lots ' when sorted gives ' bob programming is lots '
>
> Permutation 3: ' bob programming lots is ' when sorted gives ' bob programming lots is '
>
> Permutation 4: ' bob lots is programming ' when sorted gives ' bob lots is programming '
>
> Permutation 5: ' bob lots programming is ' when sorted gives ' bob lots programming is '
>
> Permutation 6: ' is bob programming lots ' when sorted gives ' is bob programming lots '
>
> Permutation 7: ' is bob lots programming ' when sorted gives ' is bob lots programming '
>
> Permutation 8: ' is programming bob lots ' when sorted gives ' is programming bob lots '
>
> Permutation 9: ' is programming lots bob ' when sorted gives ' is programming lots bob '
>
> Permutation 10: ' is lots bob programming ' when sorted gives ' is lots bob programming '

This is the output I am getting, which you can see isn't right

here is my permutation code

```
def permutations(liststring): #permutes the list of strings
    if not liststring:
        return ['']
    ret = []
    for i, d in enumerate(liststring):
        perms = permutations(liststring[:i] + liststring[i+1:])
        for perm in perms:
            ret.append(d + ' ' + perm)      
    return ret
```

Comment: Show the code you use to get the permutations. If it's generating a single string, of course sorting will return that same string. You need a *list* of strings.

Comment: length is same for lines 0 to 9. It only differs for line. Output appears right for me...

Comment: This looks correct to me... if you're just generating permutations of the same words/characters, *all* the permutations will *always* have the same length.

Comment: What are *expecting* to have happen?

Comment: @Rob Watts I am expecting it to always produce "programming lots bob is"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to sort the words of each string in a list of strings, then you need to call `sorted` on a list based on each string, rather than on the list of strings. For example:

```
def shortStringsByWordLengths(sentences):
    return [' '.join(sorted(sentence.split(), key=len)) for sentence in sentences]
```

In this code I'm creating a new list based on splitting, sorting, and then rejoining each individual sentence. `split` takes the string and turns it into a list of words separated by whitespace (i.e `'hello world!'` becomes `['hello', 'world!']`, `sorted` sorts that list by length, and join puts it back together with spaces.

Based on your comment you want it sorted by the longest first, in which case you need to add `reverse=True` to `sorted`, making it look like this:

```
def shortStringsByWordLengths(sentences):
    return [' '.join(sorted(sentence.split(), key=len, reverse=True)) for sentence in sentences]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you are attempting to do is sort the entire list of permuted strings. Won't they all be the same length after sorting, as you are just rearranging the words? If you would like to sort each string individually, you would first need to split it into individual words to be compared.

```
sorted("bob lots programming is".split(), key=len)
['is', 'bob', 'lots', 'programming']
```

Comment: If he's generating permutations of individual words, it seems very unlikely that he then wants to sort the words he just arranged.

Comment: I thought the same, although it does seem like he's looping through each string individually. Maybe it's just filler text? A more complete code sample would help.

Answer (score 1):

Solution of Rob Watts transfered to your function:

```
def my4sort(alist): #sorts the list of strings
  return [" ".join(sorted(permutation.split(),key=len,reverse=True))  for permutation in alist]
alist=["this is sparta","sparta this is","is this sparta"]
print mysort4sort(alist)
# gives ['sparta this is', 'sparta this is', 'sparta this is']
```